# Не могу получить кириллица в android-клиенте

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Добрый день. Есть сервер написанный на Java. Когда он получает сообщение, то отправляет ответ. Вот часть кода:

```
class ServeOneThread extends Thread {

long n;
String HostName;
Socket socket;
BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;

mainFigth mainFigth = new mainFigth();

//отдельный поток
public ServeOneThread(Socket s, String HostName, long n) throws IOException {
    this.n = n; //эта переменная получает по параметру № клиента, который подключился
    this.HostName = HostName;  //эта переменная получает по параметру имя клиента, который подключился
    this.socket = s; //эта переменная получает по параметру управление подключением через новый поток
    //в эту переменную будут поступать данные
    this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    //эта переменная на вывод данных клиенту
    this.out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
    start();
}


public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            //ожидаю данные
            String str = in.readLine();  //запись в переменную полученные данные
            out.println("Я получил Ваши данные, вот то что Вы прислали: "+str);
```

в IDEA File Ecoding UTF-8.
Есть андроид-клиент, который по кнопке отправляет сообщение, получает его и через ханлер выводит его в UI. Вот часть кода андроид-клиента на получение:

```
   public void run() {
    if (config.getSOCKET_CONNECTED()==false) {
        try {
            h.sendEmptyMessage(config.getSTATUS_CONNECTING()); //отсылаю в UI сообщение
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(config.getSERVER_ADDR()); // создаем объект который отображает вышеописанный IP-адрес.
            socket = new Socket(ipAddress, config.getSERVER_PORT()); // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            h.sendEmptyMessage(config.getSTATUS_CONNECTED());  //отсылаю в UI сообщение
            config.setSOCKET_CONNECTED(true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Не удалось подключится к серверу " + e);
            h.sendEmptyMessage(config.getSTATUS_NOTCONNECTED());  //отсылаю в UI сообщение
            config.setSOCKET_CONNECTED(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Не удалось подключится к серверу " + e);
            config.setSOCKET_CONNECTED(false);
        }
    }

 //пока есть конект с сервером, цикл ждет приема сообщений
    while (socket != null && socket.isConnected() && config.getSOCKET_CONNECTED()==true && !socket.isClosed()) {
        Message m = new Message();
        //m.what = 2;
        try {
            //переменная для получение данных
            String st = new String(in.readLine());
            st.getBytes("UTF-8");
            if (st == "END" || st == null) {
                //Client.stop;
                socket.close(); //закрываю сокет
                socket = null; //закрываю сокет
                threadOUT.interrupt(); //закрываю второй поток
                h.sendEmptyMessage(config.getSTATUS_NONE());
                config.setSOCKET_CONNECTED(false);
                break;
            } else {
                m.what = config.getSTATUS_MESSAGE(); //пришел ответ от сервера
                m.obj = st;
                h.sendMessage(m);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            config.setSOCKET_CONNECTED(false);
        }
    }
```

вместо слова ПРИВЕТ, сервер получает:

```
  РџР Р?Р’Р•Рў
```

а в UI мне пишет:

```
 "� ������� ���� ������, ��� �� ��� �� ��������: ПР�?ВЕТ"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как обойти эту проблему. Просто если запускаю аналогичный клиент, но на ПК, то такой проблемы нет.
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это никуда не годится

```
String st = new String(in.readLine());
st.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Вторая строка ничего не делает. И из потока строки читаются в кодировке по умолчанию. Поэтому где-то работает, а где-то нет.

Как обойти, два варианта:

1. Поток обернуть в Reader, созданный с указанием кодировки. Строки будут читаться корректно всегда и везде.
2. Из потока читать байты, потом из массива байт создать строку с указанием кодировки.

Comment: Спасибо, что отозвались на мой вопрос. Я новичок. Если Вас не затруднит, можно наглядный пример 1-го варианта, что бы я понимал как надо.

Comment: Нашео место в коде, вместо
<br/>
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
<br/>
исправить на <br/>
in = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сегодня попробую.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но не помогло(. Я ужасно расстроен. Прошу Вас, пожалуйста, покажите пример второго варианта, очень надеюсь что это поможет. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: В серверном коде тоже необходимо везде кодировку явно указать.  И, пожалуйста, исправьте на "UTF-8", я ошибся в комментарии.

Comment: я исправил на "UTF-8", но все равно не помогло. А что означает "В серверном коде тоже необходимо везде кодировку явно указать."? Где именно и как это надо указать? У меня в IDEA справа внизу File Encoding "UTF-8". Тоже самое в Android Studio.

Comment: Вот здесь  
this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));  
или здесь  
this.out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);  
Для создания всех Reader и Writer использовать конструктор с параметром для указания кодировки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, ПОМОГЛО!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй кодировку в Android Studio или в IDEA на UTF-8.

Comment: это уже давно сделано, не помогает. Но что самое интересное, что слово "ПРИВЕТ", которое туда отправлено, а потом назад, пришло почти русскими (кроме буквы "И").